# Redirect requests to other IP address in a case of link failure

Tags: redundancy, disaster-recovery

I am looking for possible solutions or ideas how to implement redundancy with connection link from two different ISP s. I have site with web server and this is primary link. I want to have redundancy in a way to get another link from other ISP, so if one link fail, other link will serve web requests. I know that my DNS record can have associate 2 IP address (primary link ip address and secondary link IP address).I know that dns resolver use round robin whan answer to dns requests, but I want to use other IP only in a case of failure primary connection link. Also I know that some browser will wait for 30 seconds and try secondary IP address but this is long time for client to wait.

Is there any other solution beside registering AS Number and routing options.

Thx

Comment: You can setup a virtualip + corosync cluster. Eg: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-apache-active-passive-cluster-using-pacemaker-on-centos-7

Comment: Is it possible for example to set up one web server and static NAT for request translation from two different public IP  on private web server IP address. Your solution is based on web server cluster and management between server. Thx for ideas